# Find the closed form generating function for the following series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

I caught this series from the classic Method Differentialis by James Stirling:

The series is

$1+\dfrac{2}{3}x+\dfrac{8}{15}x^2+\dfrac{16}{35}x^3+\dfrac{128}{315}x^4...$

I notice that the term is formed by multiplying $\dfrac{2}{3}$ to the second term, $\dfrac{4}{5}$ to the third term, $\dfrac{6}{7}$ to the fourth term, $\dfrac{8}{9}$ to fifth term.

Is there a way to find out the closed form generating function for this power series?

Comment: Find a differential equation it satisfies?

Comment: @ Lord Shark the Unknown: No find the generating function that generate this Taylor series. For example $\sin(x)=x-\dfrac{x^3}{3!}+\dfrac{x^5}{5!}-O(x^7)$. Sinx is the generating function.

Comment: Set up a recurrence relation and solve it.  $a_0=1$, $a_n=a_{n-1}\frac{2n}{2n+1}$

Comment: Generating function applies to a *sequence*, not a series. What you are looking for is called the closed form of the series

Comment: I see chicken and egg, sorry you right

Comment: @Yuriy S: You are right, I am sorry. Is there a closed form of this series?

Comment: I think you should find a closed form for the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ term of the series, and then work out a closed form for the series.

Answer (score 2):

This is the start of the expansion of 
$$\frac{\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}=1+\frac{2 x}{3}+\frac{8 x^2}{15}+\frac{16 x^3}{35}+\frac{128 x^4}{315}+\frac{256
   x^5}{693}+\frac{1024 x^6}{3003}+O\left(x^{7}\right)$$

Written as 
$$\frac{\sin ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{x}\right)}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n$$ the ratio $\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}$ generates the sequence
$$\left\{\frac{2}{3},\frac{4}{5},\frac{6}{7},\frac{8}{9},\frac{10}{11},\frac{12}{13},
   \frac{14}{15},\frac{16}{17},\frac{18}{19},\frac{20}{21},\frac{22}{23}\right\}$$ which shows the clear pattern you already noticed.

In fact,

$$c_n=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }\, \Gamma (n+1)}{2\,\Gamma \left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)}$$

Comment: How did you find out the closed form of this series? I am so curious. Did you do so with the help of computing programs? You must be a genius. :)

Comment: @JamesWarthington. In fact, I worked this series almost 50 years ago and I had it in my list of expansions (I have quite many).

Comment: Do you like infinite series? I love them after learning about them. Can you share with me your list if you don't mind.

Comment: Not all power series have a closed form right? Am I correct?

Comment: @JamesWarthington, yes, in fact most power series don't. "Closed form" is just a combination of a limited number of functions that have names, it usually only happens with particularly interesting or often encountered functions

Answer (score 1):

Let's write the ratio of terms as:

$$\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}=\frac{2(n+1)(n+1)}{2n+3} \frac{x}{n+1}$$

This makes the closed form:

$$f(x)={_2 F_1} (1,1;3/2;x)$$

Wolfram Alpha doesn't simplify it further.

That's Gauss hypergeometric function.

Sorry for being short, I'm writing from phone.

Comment: Can you show me how to use Wolfram for summing series?

Comment: In this case I didn't use Wolfram, I used the definition of hypergeometric series. As for Wolfram, it responds to Mathematica syntaxis, which you can look up in the online manual

Comment: Do you mind if I ask for the definition of Gauss hypergeometric series? Which definition did you use? Wikipedia?

Comment: Wikipedia or any other source, they all have the same definition

Comment: Wolfram Alpha can simplify it. Input 2F1(1,1;3/2;x), output $ArcSin[Sqrt[x]]/(Sqrt[1 - x] Sqrt[x])$.

Comment: @RiverLi, my mobile app didn't want to, thanks for clarifying

Comment: You gave a nice solution. You told us how to obtain the closed form (of some kinds of series).